# Resume Parser using NER in Spacy: Training Data has overlapping entities start and end index. Is there a workaround?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

Example:

Format: {content, annotations:{label:" " points[start index, last index, text: " "]}}

Lets say we have : Text in content is: "Pune University" in which I want to extract "Pune" as Location, also I want to extract "Pune University" as College name.

Please suggest me a workaround for this.

I used training data and code from Github : https://github.com/DataTurks-Engg/Entity-Recognition-In-Resumes-SpaCy and https://github.com/singhsourabh/Resume-NER . Both use same data.

I didn't expect an error since the data is used by a lot of people. Please tell me what should I do?